# When does Hazelcast evict entries?

Tags: hazelcast

I'm currently evaluating Hazelcast (3.4.2) and facing an eviction issue:

I have an IMap which is configured with a TTL of 900 seconds. After putting some entries to the map I'm making gets on a regular base to figure out when the entries are evicted. I expect the entries to be evicted after 900 seconds but sometimes they aren't evicted even after about an hour.

Does eviction especially takes place on write access to the map? The problem only seems to occur when having no write access for a long time.

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, eviction cleanup is fired after each put. 
The cleanup is also fired after the number of get operations reaches a threshold value. I do not remember the exact number but it should not be more than hundreds. 
This should be a design choice especially to avoid possible performance overhead.

Comment: Hi @javanes, thanks a lot. That's bad news for me because I have to rethink about one of my usecases for hazelcast ... hopefully I'll find a solution.